# Sending messages to functions in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor

I'm working my way through Bruce Tate's [*Seven Languages in Seven Weeks*](http://pragprog.com/book/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks) and am having a hard time understanding his implementation of `sizer.scala` (Scala: Day 3). In particular, consider the following Singleton object

```
object PageLoader {
    def getPageSize(url : String) = Source.fromURL(url).mkString.length
}
```

and the following method that, using actors, calculates the number of characters in each web page given by the `urls` array.

```
def getPageSizeConcurrently() = {
    val caller = self

    for(url <- urls) {
        actor { caller ! (url, PageLoader.getPageSize(url)) }
    }

    for(i <- 1 to urls.size) {
        receive {
            case (url, size) =>
                println("Size for " + url + ": " + size)
        }
    }
}
```

1. What does **self** refer to? `getPageSizeConcurrently`? Is it possible for **self** to refer to a function?
2. Assuming that **self** *does* refer to `getPageSizeConcurrently`, is this considered to be pretty standard in the Scala world? Why send messages to a function instead of an object, or vice versa?

**UPDATE:** The code in question only uses **self** once, but it does start with the following `import` statements.

```
import scala.io._
import scala.actors._
import Actor._
```

Looking through [the Scala API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.package), it appears that [the `Actor` singleton object has a `self` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.Actor$). Even if that's the `self` assigned to `caller`, though, I don't see why the `receive` block would be executed.

Comment: What class or object has `getPageSizeConcurrently` as one of its methods?

Comment: @Rex Nothing, as far as I can tell. I've omitted a few other methods (and the definition of `urls`) here, but otherwise this is verbatim from the book. The only class or object declared in the code is `PageLoader`, as shown above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a self method on the Actor companion object. From the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/actors/Actor%24.html):

> Returns the currently executing actor. Should be used instead of this in all blocks of code executed by actors.

I'm guessing that your code has imported the Actor object, and that it is the self method on the Actor object your code is calling. This way you get a reference to the main actor thread you're in, and the anonymous actors you start to get page size can send the message back to the thread you're in.

Comment: Interesting! So there's a distinction between the main actor thread returned by Actor's `self` method and the anonymous actors in the code above? I would have thought that the "currently executing actor" would actually be one of the anonymous actors that was started...

Comment: No, there's no distinction, but at the time you call self, the currently executing actor is the main actor thread. So that's what the caller reference points to later when you use it in the creation of the anonymous actors.

Comment: Ah, of course, that makes sense. So the following calls to `receive` are implicitly invoked on the main actor thread, right?

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say implicitly invoked, as that might be interpreted as implicit in the special scala sense of the word. "receive" is a normal method call just as "self" further up, and invoked in the same main thread, yes.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is not a Scala keyword.

Although I don't have the book, Scala classes allow aliases for themselves; `self` is commonly chosen.  Here's why you might want to do that (not counting that you can restrict the type that the class can be when you specify the alias):

```
class A {
  self =>
  val a = 7
  class B {
    val a = 7             // Uh-oh, we've shadowed the parent class a.
    val outerA = self.a   // Whew, we haven't lost it!
  }
}
```

So, `self` is almost certainly the class that implements the `getPageSizeConcurrently` method.

Without seeing more of the code, I don't have any insight into why exactly it's written this way (looks kind of strange to me).  But there's no weird message-to-method going on here.

(Incidentally, note that it is formally possible to define an actor that extends a `Function` trait.  So you could, in fact, send a message to a function (function object, not a method).  But the syntax wouldn't look like what you've got above.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! You were correct in guessing that I thought of `self` as a Scala keyword. I've updated my question to incorporate this new information.

Answer (score 1):

Although actors are not bound to threads as they were in the earlier versions of Scala, `self` is comparable to `Thread.current`. You use it, because `Thread.current` does not have the necessary methods to view the current thread as an actor.

*"What class or object has getPageSizeConcurrently as one of its methods?"* - [Rex Kerr](http://Rex%20Kerr)

*"Nothing, as far as I can tell..."* - [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/709202/chris)

I assume `self` tries to treat the current thread as an actor.

Note: Be careful, when using `self` in the REPL.