# Explain this concurrent scala code

Tags: scala, concurrency

I have found this code example, that is part of a "web crawler" written in Scala:

```
 def getPageSizeConcurrently() = {
        val caller = self
 
        for (url <- urls) {
            actor { caller ! (url, PageLoader.getPageSize(url)) }
        }
 
        for (i <- 1 to urls.size) {
            receive {
                case (url, size) =>
                    println(url + ": " + size)
                case _ =>
                    println("Shouldn't happen")
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to know if I am getting it right.

The second line "var caller = self" is that something equal to erlangs self(), which is returning a PID?

The fifth line that starts with actor, is that creating a new actor-process that is sending a message to the PID caller with a tupel (url, PageLoader.getPageSize(url))?

Comment: This code can not be explained without more context. My guess is that it is using the (deprecated) Scala actor library. If you want to use actors I recommend you use [Akka](http://akka.io/).

Answer (score 0):

`self` is most likely a reference to the `ActorRef` of the current actor (or something similar).

`caller` is most likely a reference to the `ActorRef` of the calling actor (or something similar).

There is probably no `PID` involved.

[Typesafe activator](http://www.typesafe.com/platform/getstarted) has some examples using Akka

Answer (score 0):

`self` is a reference to the ActorRef instance that contains that actor.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in accepted answer for [Sending messages to functions in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743169/sending-messages-to-functions-in-scala) `self` is currently executing actor.

On line 5, a new actor is created for each URL, which

- calculates page size of given URL
- prepares a tuple containing url & it's size
- sends this tuple to the caller (getPageSizeConcurrently)

`caller` variable is needed because self cannot be used to refer current actor (getPageSizeConcurrently) within actor block on line 5. If `self` were used instead of `caller` like:

```
actor { self ! (url, PageLoader.getPageSize(url)) }
```

it would refer to that sub actor.

Then on line 8, our methods start waiting for messages from all created sub actors. That loop will not terminate until it receives urls.size number of messages. ([ReceiveTimeout](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.3/index.html#akka.actor.ReceiveTimeout$) would be useful here)